# Permutation of Array using Recursion : Python

Tags: python, arrays, recursion, permutation

I am trying to get permutation of array using recursion with the below code

```
ans = []
def helper(a, i):
    if i == len(a):
        ans.append(a)
    for j in range(i, len(a)):
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        helper(a, i+1)
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]

helper([1,2,3],0)
    
print(ans)
```

With the above code I am getting below result which is wrong

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Please help me what's wrong with my code

Comment: By the way, in the eventuality you *need* permutations and are not just practicing coding, there exists `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: You are using a list here. When we speak of arrays in python, we usually mean fixed size [numpy arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_creating_arrays.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are editing `a` after you appended it to `ans`. The following code demonstrates the problem:

```py
ans = []
a = [1, 2, 3]

ans.append(a)
print(ans)

a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
print(ans) # The elements in ans are swapped too
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
[[2, 1, 3]]
```

As you can see, when we change `a`, `ans` gets changed too. This is because when we append `a` to `ans`, `ans` only stores the memory location of `a`. Both `ans[0]` and `a` give you the same object. As a lot of python built-in types, such as `int`, `float` and `str` are immutable (the object itsself can't be changed), this is usually no problem. But lists are mutable, which means that the object itself can be changed. But, as both `ans[0]` and `a` are the same object, changing `a` will thus also change `ans`.

We can prevent this by forcing python to store another list in `ans`. We can do this appending `a.copy()` instead of `a` to `ans`. `a.copy()` returns the exact same list as `a`, but stored in a different object. Changes in `a` thus won't be reflected in `a.copy()`. If we change the above code to the following, we do get the expected output:

```py
ans = []
a = [1, 2, 3]

ans.append(a.copy())
print(ans)

a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
print(ans) # The elements in ans aren't swapped.
```

The same problem applies to your code. In the line `ans.append(a)`, you are appending `a` to `ans` without copying it. This means that you are continuously appending the same object to `ans`. As you are changing `a` later on, all elements of `ans` gets changed too. This results in `ans` containing only the restored starting version of `a` at the end.

You can solve the problem by appending only copies of `a` to `ans`. This makes that changes in `a` later on are not reflected in `ans`:

```py
ans = []
def helper(a, i):
    if i == len(a):
        ans.append(a.copy())
    for j in range(i, len(a)):
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        helper(a, i+1)
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]

helper([1,2,3],0)
    
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the list you are appending to the `ans` is only the reference and it is getting changed to the original list after executing the last statement of the for loop. Try to copy the list instead and check the result.

```py
ans = []

def helper(a, i):
    if i == len(a):
        ans.append(a[:])
    for j in range(i, len(a)):
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]
        helper(a, i+1)
        a[i],a[j] = a[j], a[i]

helper([1,2,3],0)
    
print(ans)
# Output
# [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

Here `a[:]` copies the list and appends it to the `ans`.